# Does FrescoImageViewer - stfalcon still work for android (java)?

Tags: java, android, android-image, fresco

> Could not find com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0.
> Required by: project :app

I'm getting this error while building my project, when I implement "com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0" in build:gradle

Can someone suggest me a way out?